# "401 Unauthorized" error while doing http post (cloned from curl command) in Android

Tags: android, http, post, curl, authentication

i know that i'm not first, but i did search and didn't found solution.
First of all i need to make this:

```
curl -user1:pass1 - X POST -d"data" http://www.mysite.com/pushes.xml
```

But i don't want to use curl lib for such easy request, beacuse i think that solution must be easy and painless. I've found this [http login example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java), and tried to use it with

```
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user1"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass1"));
```

But i think that tags "username" and "password" are wrong... and i just unable to get them.. so I ask you about help. Please help me to understand what i need to do to get thrrough this login. Thanks will be guaranteed :)

P.S. in the response i get msg "HTTP Basic: Access denied". But curl command works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if server returns 401 you need to pass credential via special authenticator or header parameters:

```
    httpPost.addHeader(RestHelper.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, RestHelper.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_VALUE);

where 

    AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_VALUE = "Basic " + Base64Encoder.encode ("user:password");
    AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
```

or

```
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("server.com", 443, AuthScope.ANY_SCHEME),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(LOGIN_VALUE, PASSWORD));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the API you are using. I had the similar problem until I checked it and it was "user", not "username".
So change `nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user1"));`
to `nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "user1"));` and give it a try.